# Changing header size dynamically in Reporting services

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I am working with a report in Reporting services. I need to show the parameters the users selected in the header. When the user selects "select All" I have to show all the selected values in the header. I am able to do all these things just fine.

My main issue is when the select list is too long the header cuts off my list.

Is there way or setting thru which the header sizes can change dynamically based on the size of the textbox inside header which is growing dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've run into this issue. I do not believe there is a way to make it expand any longer.

My work-around has been one of two options:

1) Display "All" instead of listing them all out

2) Move that information to a textbox in the body of the report, above the report data.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I also wanted to do display "All" but its not so easy to do in ssrs2005 which I am using. In ssrs2008 it can be done easily. I do like you other idea. I was thinking along that line but wanted to make sure before I went that way.

Comment: If you are using a dataset to populate your parameter list, you can simply create a new variable "ParamTest" that is the count of that dataset.  In your textbox which you are displaying the parameter, you can say something like =iif(Parameters!ParamTest.Value = Parameters!SelectAll.Count, "All", JOIN(Parameters!SelectAll.Label, " - "))